# C++ equivalent for passing a lambda function as an argument in python

Tags: python, c++, function, lambda, conditional-statements

In python you can just pass a lambda function as an argument, like the following:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        self.attr1 = a1
        self.attr2 = a2

class ThingList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.things = [Thing(1,2), Thing(3,4), Thing(1,4)]

    def getThingsByCondition(self, condition):
        thingsFound = []
        for thing in self.things:
            if condition(thing):
                thingsFound.append(thing)
        return thingsFound

things = tl.getThingsByCondition(lambda thing: thing.attr1==1)
print things
```

Is there a way to do something similar in C++? I need to do this because I want to search a `vector` of objects for objects fulfilling certain criteria.

---

Okay, I tried to solve it like this:
I should mention that the "things" I'm managing in a vector are employees and I want to find Employees fulfilling certain conditions.

```
employee_vector getEmployeeByCondition(function<bool(const Employee&)> condition) {
    employee_vector foundEmployees;
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {
        Employee e = employees.at(i);
        if (condition(e)) {
            foundEmployees.push_back(e);
        }
    }
    return foundEmployees;
}

employee_vector getEmployeeByBirthday(Date bday) {
    employee_vector found;
    found = getEmployeeByCondition([](Employee e) {return e.birthday == bday;});
    return found;
}
```

Now the problem is that I obviously can not use `bday` in the lambda function in `getEmployeeByBirthday`, as it is a local variable.

Comment: Look interesting, thank you. The reason I'm asking is also that I need to find objects by comparing a variety of attributes. Now I don't want to write a function which loops over the vector checking for some condition each time, because then I'd have to write about 6 actually identical functions - and I don't think that's the right way. Thats why I'd like to keep the condition variable and just pass it to the function.

Comment: just a side unrelated note, in python you could simply implement your getThingsByCondition method as: def getThingsByCondition(self, condition): return filter(condition, self.things)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can pass lambdas to functions.

You can use templates:

```
template <typename Func>
void foo (Func f) {
    f();
}

foo([]{ std::cout << "Hello"; });
```

Or `std::function`:

```
void foo (std::function<void()> f) {
    f();
}

foo([]{ std::cout << "Hello"; });
```

If you want to search a `std::vector` for an object fulfilling some criteria, you can use `std::find_if`:

```
std::find_if(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), 
             [](auto& el) { return /*does this fulfil criteria?*/; });
```

As for `getThingsByCondition` it could look something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename...Ts, typename Func>
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>
filter(std::vector<T,Ts...>& container, const Func& func) {
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>> ret;

    for (auto& el : container) {
        if (func(el)) ret.push_back(std::ref(el));   
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This could certainly be improved to work with different containers, etc. And it'll almost certainly not work for `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: Looks interesting, but when trying the second one Visual Studio tells me that "function is not a pattern". I'm declaring the function like this `vector<Employee> getEmployeeByCondition(function<bool(const Employee&)> condition) {...}`

Comment: What version of MSVC are you using? And did you `#include <functional>`?

Comment: No, I did not, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can design `getThingsByCondition` like

```
using things_vec = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Thing>>;

things_vec getThingsByCondition(std::function<bool(const Thing&)> condition);
```

You can call `getThingsByCondition` function using a `lambda` like

```
auto things = getThingsByCondition([](const Thing& thing) { return thing.attr1 == 1; })
```

Comment: It'd probably be better for `getThingsByCondition` to return something like `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Thing>>` to avoid copies and let you modify the found objects.